# Possibility to enable Clipboard API in Microsoft Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams, clipboard

I am developing an application for Microsoft Teams, and one of the functionalities in said application would need to be a simple Copy to clipboard -button for links. These links are not visible to the end user in the UI.

The issue is that Microsoft Teams embeds applications in an iframe, and the [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) is not enabled in that iframe.

My question is, is it possible to enable the clipboard API?

I discovered this issue through trial and error. When clicking on the button that has the copy-function, there is an error saying `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The Clipboard API has been blocked because of a permissions policy applied to the current document. See [link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) for more details`

I am aware that there is a deprecated execCommand API, but using deprecated APIs that may be dropped whenever is not ideal.

Comment: We are checking this with engineering team. We will let you know once we get any updates on it.

Answer (score 0):

Clipboard API feature is currently not supported in Teams.

If you wish you can suggest this feature here:
[Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)